# How to open / decrypt a password protected word-file (docx) with PHP

Tags: php, encryption, ms-word, passwords, docx

I am trying to open a word-file (.docx) programmatically with PHP. This word-file is protected and encrypted with a password so it's content cannot be display without providing the password. Of course I do know the password.

But how can I manage to open this word-file with PHP by providing the password?

The only PHP-library that at least mentions password protection is the great PhpOffice/PhpWord - but it does not support opening password protected files: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/357

*Please note that there is a slight difference between password protection against unwanted changes and - this is my case - to protect it against unauthorized opening.*

TIA

Comment: Are you referring to the "Information Rights Management Service" or the simple "Restrict Formatting" options that are available and include the use of a password... or another technique?

Comment: @RamRaider - The docx-file can only be opened after providing a password. It is not about restriciting formatting, it is about opening the document. I don't know the proper term for that technology, but I assume it's the "IRMS".

Comment: No, it's sounds like standard file password protection, not IRMS. In the Word object model that would be the Password argument of the Documents.Open method. But if PHP works only with the ZIP package and the Office Open XML file format then it cannot be used to "open" a password-protected, encrypted file. These are in binary format, not Open XML.

Comment: I am kind of confused. I would assume that it is in the Word object model because I am able to open it in e.g. VBA with the mentioned password-argument: 

Documents.Open(filePath, PasswordDocument:=password)

(But I also have to add that I have no deeper knowledge of this topic, so any suggestion to change the title or question is highly appreciated :) )

Answer (score 1):

I welcome you to check out my [PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword](https://github.com/jaydadhania08/PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword) repo.

First decrypt the file with password, and then use the decrypted file with PHPWord.

Here is an example:

```
require_once('PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword.php');

$encryptedFilePath = '../path/to/encrypted/file.docx';
$password = 'mypassword'; // password to "open" the file
$decryptedFilePath = '../path/to/decrypted/file.docx';

decrypt($encryptedFilePath, $password, $decryptedFilePath);

// now you can use PHPWord with $decryptedFilePath
```

**Note:** This is an experimental code, so use with caution. DO NOT use in production!